# How to remove [img] bbcode with php

Tags: php, regex

I have a string

```
$content = "your image is [img]url to image.png[/img] now you can use it";
```

With php script I want

```
$content = "your image is now you can use it";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$content = "your image is [img]url to image.png[/img] now you can use it";
echo preg_replace("/\[img\](.+?)\[\/img\]/i", '', $content);
```

Output:

```
your image is  now you can use it
```

Comment: Would that work properly if there were multiple instances in the same string?

Comment: That's neat - I thought the `.+` was a greedy operator, so I assume the `.+?` is modifying its behaviour somehow?

Comment: @andrewsi: Yeah, the `?` makes it lazy and makes the pattern match as few times as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a single-instance of `[img][/img]`, you can use a combination of [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$first = substr($content, 0, strpos($content, '[img]'));
$end = substr($content, strpos($content, '[/img]') + 6);
$content = $first . $end;
```

If there can be multiple instances within the same string, you'll need to put it in a loop:

```
$openImg = strpos($content, '[img]');
while ($openImg !== false) {
    $first = substr($content, 0, $openImg);
    $end = substr($content, strpos($content, '[/img]') + 6);
    $content = $first . $end;

    $openImg = strpos($content, '[img]');
}
```